# Is the following summation statement well defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Summation from 0 to infinity P(E) < infinity.

How does this statement help us in the sense of making deductions? I mean, isn't stating that something is less than infinity redundant?

Can't I say that infinity isn't well-defined to be used in such a comparison? I mean if I say that a sum approaches infinity can't I also say that it is smaller than some infinity and bigger than another?

I guess it indicates a converging summation but there has to be some other way to show that? I'm confused about this.

I'm sorry but I'm not used to latex.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers, 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n < \infty$$
is just a convenient notational convention for the statement 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \ \text{converges}$$
This makes some sense, because the only alternative is that the sum diverges to $+\infty$, which would be written as
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \infty$$

Comment: Ok, so it's just a notation and I was going for a deductive analysis. Thanks.